# Why do I get empty $REQUEST_URI after .htaccess redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried to customize the instructions in http://alistapart.com/article/succeed
to my needs - redirect all *.html pages into dispatcher.php file that parses the URL.

in my .htaccess file, I added

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(html)$ dispatcher.php  [L,NC]
```

but all the parameters in dispatcher.php are empty:

```
  echo "1. " . $REQUEST_URI . "<br />";      
  echo "2. " . $DOCUMENT_ROOT . "<br />";    
  echo "3. " . $SCRIPT_FILENAME . "<br />";
```

**Why dont I get these parameters?**

---

**meanwhile** I avoid the problem by using the following:
in .htaccess -

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(html)$ dispatcher.php?u=$1  [L,NC]
```

and in dispatcher.php -

```
$u = $_GET['u']; // and use this $u parameter . . .
```

---

**original sample code**:

```
RewriteRule !.(gif|jpg|png|css)$ /your_web_root/index.php    # in .htaccess



if(file_exists($DOCUMENT_ROOT.$REQUEST_URI)
    and ($SCRIPT_FILENAME!=$DOCUMENT_ROOT.$REQUEST_URI)
    and ($REQUEST_URI!="/")){ . . .  // in index.php
```

Comment: `$REQUEST_URI` or  $_`SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$REQUEST_URI, $DOCUMENT_ROOT...**  are not variables!

you should use

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
...
```

p.s. you can simply:

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```